# When I run this web app it render a blank page without any error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

This is a App.js file. I am making a react Instagram clone with firestore database (Attributes => username, caption, imageUrl) but with this code it renders a blank page but it works if I use with hard code data.

Please Help. Thanks.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import {db} from './firebase';
import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore"; //docs


function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts]= useState([]);

// useEffect runs a peice of code based on a specific condition
  useEffect (() => {

    //everytime a new post is added this code fires.
     onSnapshot(
      collection(db, "posts"),
      (snapshot) => { setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
          // set our posts to(from that snapshot.go get docs.map through every single one(get each doc=> each docs data e.g username etc.))
      }
    );
    
    }, []);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className='app_header'>
          <img className='app_headerImage' src="Logo-Instagram.png" alt="instagram-logo" />

        </div>
        
        <h1>Hi This is Mahad</h1>

        {
          posts.map(post=>(
            <Post username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageUrl={post.imageUrl} />
          ))
        }

      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I am expecting that it render posts from firestore and show it on timeline.

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: You need to debug commenting out small piece of code at a time. If the app starts running again that's where the issue is.

Comment: Nope, It just says "compiled successfully!"

Comment: I am using this tutorial which uses firebase v8 code but now I want v9 code to get it to work. Following code needs to be changed according to v9


```
db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => { 
     setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    });
```

Comment: I see. Seems like that is the issue then. You then need to refer to the v9 docs.